# year not displaying on linux

Tags: c, linux, unix

Hope someone can help. I am fixing a problem in someone’s’ C code that was written a long time ago and he has since moved on.

The piece of code outputs the timestamp of a particular file. The code works fine when run on windows but when it is run on Linux it displays the Year incorrectly.  The year is not displaying on linux, it shows 35222.  Does anyone have any idea what is the problem here?

Thanks

Windows output:

```
Source file: test.dtl, Created: Mon, 27 May, 2013 at 16:13:20
```

Linux output:

```
Source file: test.dtl, Created: Mon, 27 May, 35222 at 16:13:20
```

The function in C code:

```
void SummaryReport ( report_t *report, char *dtlName)
{      
       LogEntry(L"SummaryReport entry\n");

       int                  i;
       wchar_t              *rootStrType,*localStr,timeStr[48];
       wchar_t              fileBuff[64];

       struct tm *timeVals;
       timeVals = localtime (&logHdr.date);
       wcsftime (timeStr,47,L"%a, %#d %b, %Y at %X",timeVals);

       /*  Print the header information  */
       DisplayReportFile (report);
       ReportEntry (report,L" Filesystem Audit Summary Report\n\n");
       ReportEntry (report,L"Source file: %s, Created: %ls\n\n",dtlName,timeStr);
       ReportEntry (report,L"Server: %ls",srvrName);
…
}
```

Comment: Is the date--specifically the year--set correctly on the Linux system?

Comment: Linux is just that much more advanced than Windows.

Comment: I guess, this is due to the different time bases used in Windows and Unix. Unix counts seconds since 1.1.1970 - I don't know what Windows does, but I'd wager something different...

Comment: Where does `logHdr.date` come from?

Comment: Try printing out `timeVals->tm_year` to make sure you have the correct tm value.

Comment: are you running it with Wine or did you recompile for Linux?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure the Linux versions of strftime and derivatives grok the `%#d` syntax. At least the man-page on my current system doesn't mention it...

Answer (score 1):

Verified on a minimal example and it "works-for-me". Does this show the right time?

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <time.h>


int main() {
        wchar_t timeStr[48];
        struct tm *timeVals;
        time_t now = time(NULL);
        timeVals = localtime(&now);
        wcsftime(timeStr, 47, L"%a, %#d %b, %Y at %X", timeVals);
        wprintf(timeStr);
        return 0;
}
```

If yes, check the file itself - if you're sharing the filesystem, maybe there's some weird issue with the file timestamp itself? (or with understanding the fs metadata)

Answer (score 1):

In case `wcsftime()` itself calls `localtime()`, insure the results of your call are not corrupted.

```
struct tm timeVals;
timeVals = *localtime (&logHdr.date);
wcsftime (timeStr,47,L"%a, %#d %b, %Y at %X", &timeVals);
```

---

`localtime()` saves its results in a static struct tm *somewhere*.  The address (pointer) to that location is returned.  Subsequent calls to  `localtime()` or `gmtime()` alter the struct tm.  I suspect the call to `wcsftime()` indirectly does that in Linux.

BTW: localtime() could return NULL, so safer code would check the localtime() return value.

Your may want to look into the `localtime_s()`